# Final Identifier is necessary, why?

Tags: java

I try to write a program which `convert string to integer`.
But in defining method, it gets error in `identifier`, and tells it should be `final`.
***"Illegal modifier for parameter stringtoInteger; only final is permitted"***
does anybody know why it should be `final`?

```
public class StringtoInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        public static void stringtoInteger(){

            int i = 24;
            String str = Integer.toString(i);

            int j = 23;
            String str2 = "" + j;

            int k = 22;
            String str3 = " " + k;

            System.out.println(str + "\t" + str2 + "\t" + str3);
            System.out.println(str + str2 + str3);

            System.out.println();

            System.out.println(i + "\t" + j + "\t" + k);
            System.out.println(i  + j  + k);
        }   

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have a method inside a method in Java.

Comment: Take `stringtoInteger` method out from main method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put a the method *inside* the main method.

Either drop the `public static void stringtoInteger(){` method declaration, and put the code directly in `main`:

```
public class StringtoInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = 24;
        String str = Integer.toString(i);
        ...
```

or move `stringtoInteger` outside of main (and call it from main if you want it to execute)

```
public class StringtoInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        stringtoInteger();
    }

    public static void stringtoInteger() {

        int i = 24;
        String str = Integer.toString(i);

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. Can we have two methods, e.g. _method 1_ and _method 2_, then define a variable, e.g. **str** in both? or they should have **different names**?

Comment: @Hengameh, you can use the same name in different methods. The `{ ... }` delimits the *scope* of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
public class StringtoInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringtoInt.stringtoInteger();
    }

    public static void stringtoInteger() {
        int i = 24;
        String str = Integer.toString(i);

        int j = 23;
        String str2 = "" + j;

        int k = 22;
        String str3 = " " + k;

        System.out.println(str + "\t" + str2 + "\t" + str3);
        System.out.println(str + str2 + str3);
        System.out.println(i + "\t" + j "\t" + k);
        System.out.println(i + j + k);
    }
}
```